# Create a zip file for nodejs distribution without dev dependencies (bundling)

Tags: node.js, npm

I wrote a set of functions and I want to create a zip file containing all stuff necessary for production. So I want to exclude all stuff used for dev (Nothing from `devDependencies`).

Why do I need to create the ZIP? I know that It's possible to install dependencies in the server, but serverless platforms are expecting a zip with all dependencies included to avoid long time start-ups (cold start). Also, I want to integrate the deployment with Terraform.

The problem is that all solutions that I found googling don't exclude dev dependencies and transitive dev dependencies automatically. Basically, they take all from `node_modules` and the root and make a zip, including stuff that is not necessary for production, like unit test and tools used for developing.

I'm looking something like:

- *sbt-assembly* or *sbt-native-packager* in Scala.
- *Maven Shade Plugin* or *Maven Assembly Plugin* in Java.
- *python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel* in Python.

Important: I don't want a solution where I need to manually specify the list of dependencies to exclude. I have this information in the `package.json` and the method should use this information to know what to put in the zip file.

Comment: I found this [post](https://medium.com/adobetech/quick-tip-packaging-node-js-dependencies-for-openwhisk-b6f9c87c3ec1), but I can not believe that this is the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I was not able to find a standard way to do it.** All posts that I found are workarounds and homemade solutions, so it looks like there is not a standard way to assembly or package customs applications like in other languages. I think that this is a big gap in Nodejs world. In my opinion, `packaging or assembly or whatever` should be a common configurable module in the core, shared by npm, webpack, etc...

Next, the script that I wrote to do the following steps:

1. Execute npm pack to package *only production* dependencies.
2. Search the zipped tar generated.
3. Decompress the file to be able to manipulate the content.
4. Generate a new zip without the package folder.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const rimraf = require('rimraf');
const child_process = require('child_process');
const decompress = require('decompress');
const decompressTargz = require('decompress-targz');
const glob = require('glob');
const zip = require('zip-a-folder');

const zipFileName = 'functionapp.zip';
const targetFolder = './build';

// Create temporal folder to work in.
if (fs.existsSync(targetFolder)) {
    rimraf.sync(targetFolder);
}
fs.mkdirSync(targetFolder);

// Execute npm pack to package only production dependencies.
child_process.exec(
    'npm pack ../',
    {cwd: targetFolder},
    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if(error != null) {
            console.error(`Error executing npm pack: ${stderr}`);
        } else {
            console.log(stdout);

            // Search the tar generated
            glob(`${targetFolder}/*.tgz`, {}, (err, files) => {
                if(err != null) {
                    console.error(`Error finding packaged file: ${err}`);
                } else {

                    // Decompress the file to remove the package root folder and generate zip.
                    decompress(files[0], targetFolder, {
                        plugins: [
                            decompressTargz()
                        ]
                    }).then(() => {
                        console.log('Files decompressed');

                        // Zip content to create the deployable file.
                        zip.zipFolder(
                            `${targetFolder}/package`,
                            `${targetFolder}/${zipFileName}`,
                            error=> console.error(error)
                        );
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

usually, you don't want to pack any package dependencies (`node_modules` directory), since some packages are being compiled during installation (`npm install`).

if you still want to do it, i will advise you to consider packing it in a [docker images](https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container).

you can keep files out of the package using [`.npmignore`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package) and leverage [`npm pack`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/pack) to create a `tar.gz` of your module, which you can deliver (for instance, publishing it to npm registry).

depending on the propose of your npm module, you  might like to leverage [`npx`](https://github.com/npm/npx) and execute your module from github\npm\etc.

Comment: In my project, only few dependencies are used. `npm install --production` generate 912K `node_modules` folder, vs 23M with dev dependencies. I don't want to push 23M when it is not necessary at all. A Docker image is even heaviest. Using .npmignore to exclude dev dependencies means duplicate information that it is in package.json :(

Comment: you didn't understand me correctly, there is no need to ship the dependencies, just install them on the desired host (which can me any machine or a container)

Comment: Ok, I get it now. I added in the question why I need a zip with dependencies. I was playing with `npm pack` and I wrote a script to create a tar in a temporal folder, un pack and pack again unzip format without the package root folder. But this solution is so ugly. I can not believe that there is not another way.

Comment: There are use cases where a zip inclusive of node_modules is needed, for example AWS Lambda Node.js zip deployments: size is proportional to cost and some modules are available in the runtime already (aws sdk packages for example)